# CSS Slideshow is taking too long to start

Tags: css, slideshow, automatic-updates

I'm using an example for creating a pure CSS slideshow. All works great except when I add a new slide the behavior changes. Before, the slides moved from left to right with the next one to enter following slowly. Now it kind of just slides reveal the other one under.

I know it a timing problem but I cannot see how to calculate it. Try with the original code of five slide and a execution time of 28 (4 slides multiply by 7 second each) then look at the transition. It did'nt show the fifth slide. Now, to add the fifth one change the execution time to 35 (5 slides multiply by 7 seconds each) and see what appends. The fifth slide show but the transition between the slide differ from the test with timing of 28. The first side takes too long to start and it messes up the rest of the timing, and I don't know why.

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
*,
*::before,
*::after { box-sizing: border-box; }

html,
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #3c3c3c;
}

.card {
  position: relative;  
  width: 700px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.card::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 900;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(140, 22, 115, 0.2);
}

.card_part {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 7;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;  
  transform: translateX( 700px );
  background-image: url( http://www.cosat.biz/fichiers/img/Img1.png );  
  animation: opaqTransition 28s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0, 0.97) infinite;
/* change to 35 for 5 slides*/
}

.card_part.card_part-two {
  z-index: 6;
  background-image: url( http://www.cosat.biz/fichiers/img/Img2.png );
  animation-delay: 7s;
}

.card_part.card_part-three {
  z-index: 5;
  background-image: url( http://www.cosat.biz/fichiers/img/Img3.png );
  animation-delay: 14s;
}

.card_part.card_part-four {
  z-index: 4;
  background-image: url( http://www.cosat.biz/fichiers/img/Img4.png );
  animation-delay: 21s;
}

.card_part.card_part-five {
  z-index: 3;
  background-image: url( http://www.cosat.biz/fichiers/img/Img5.png );
  animation-delay: 28s;
}

@keyframes opaqTransition {
  3% { transform: translateX( 0 ); }
  25% { transform: translateX( 0 ); }
  28% { transform: translateX( -700px ); }
  100% { transform: translateX( -700px ); }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Slideshow container -->
<div class="card">
  <div class="card_part card_part-one"></div> 
   <!-- Photo 2 -->
  <div class="card_part card_part-two"></div>
  <!-- Photo 3 -->
  <div class="card_part card_part-three"></div>
  <!-- Photo 4 -->
  <div class="card_part card_part-four"></div>
   <!-- Photo 5 -->
  <div class="card_part card_part-five"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, english is not my language...

Answer (score 0):

I simply just changed the `animation` time to 5s, and everything went a whole lot faster. You can change the timing to whatever fits your needs.

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
*,
*::before,
*::after { box-sizing: border-box; }

html,
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #3c3c3c;
}

.card {
  position: relative;  
  width: 700px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.card::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 900;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(140, 22, 115, 0.2);
}

.card_part {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 7;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;  
  transform: translateX( 700px );
  background-image: url( https://github.com/Flat-Pixels/assets_hosting/blob/master/picture_slides/1.jpg?raw=true );  
  animation: opaqTransition 5s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0, 0.97) infinite;
/* change to 35 for 5 slides*/
}

.card_part.card_part-two {
  z-index: 6;
  background-image: url( https://github.com/Flat-Pixels/assets_hosting/blob/master/picture_slides/2.jpg?raw=true );
  animation-delay: 7s;
}

.card_part.card_part-three {
  z-index: 5;
  background-image: url( https://github.com/Flat-Pixels/assets_hosting/blob/master/picture_slides/3.jpg?raw=true );
  animation-delay: 14s;
}

.card_part.card_part-four {
  z-index: 4;
  background-image: url( https://github.com/Flat-Pixels/assets_hosting/blob/master/picture_slides/4.jpg?raw=true );
  animation-delay: 21s;
}

.card_part.card_part-five {
  z-index: 4;
  background-image: url( https://github.com/Flat-Pixels/assets_hosting/blob/master/picture_slides/2.jpg?raw=true );
  animation-delay: 21s;
}

@keyframes opaqTransition {
  3% { transform: translateX( 0 ); }
  25% { transform: translateX( 0 ); }
  28% { transform: translateX( -700px ); }
  100% { transform: translateX( -700px ); }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Slideshow container -->
<div class="card">
  <div class="card_part card_part-one"></div> 
   <!-- Photo 2 -->
  <div class="card_part card_part-two"></div>
  <!-- Photo 3 -->
  <div class="card_part card_part-three"></div>
  <!-- Photo 4 -->
  <div class="card_part card_part-four"></div>
   <!-- Photo 5 -->
  <!-- div class="card_part card_part-five" --></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```